# Ubuntu 14.04 installation problems

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, live-cd

When installing Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit I get this error message:

```
stdin:not a typewriter
mounting /dev/sdb3 on /cdrom failed: Invalid argument
failed to change /etc/passwd to 600
buffer io error on device sdb*
```

It then boots into the live CD.

I run the installation, reboot, and get dropped into BusyBox.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

By mount error, I suspect your CD/DVD reader may be failing.

Please try making a bootable [USB drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).